# Get the value of Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have the following code in one of my Razor view in an MVC project: `<b>Item Code: </b>@Html.DropDownList("ItemID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Items)`

I would like to access the value of the drop down list later in an `@Ajax.ActionLink` in the Razor view. Is there a way to access the value of the drop down list **in the view**?

Comment: You mean selected value? If not you have already your values `(SelectList)ViewBag.Items`

Comment: Yes the selected value.

Comment: User can change the value so you should manage it by JS

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to get the current selected value -

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a special library (like jQuery) to deal with your DOM elements, you can use vanilla Javascript as per the following example:

```js
//get the element by its ID value    
var dropdownElement = document.getElementById("ddlItems");

// now we have a reference to the dropdown field, let's read the selected value (or text):    
// 1- selected value
var selectedValue = dropdownElement.options[dropdownElement.selectedIndex].value;

// 2- selected text
var selectedText = dropdownElement.options[dropdownElement.selectedIndex].text;

// display a popup with selected text and value
window.alert("selected value is: (" + selectedValue + "), and selected text is: (" + selectedText + ").");
```

```html
<select id="ddlItems">
  <option value="1">1st item</option>
  <option value="2">2nd item</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">3rd item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're attempting to pass selected value from `DropDownList` helper into `@Ajax.ActionLink` helper from the view, which is impossible because `@Ajax.ActionLink` helper processed and rendered server-side before sending to browser.

You can use `@Html.ActionLink` helper without `routeValues` parameter instead and set `id` attribute of that anchor tag:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Item", "TargetAction", "TargetController", null, new { id = "link" })
```

Then use unobtrusive AJAX to handle `click` event of that link and pass selected value from dropdown element there:

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get selected value from dropdownlist
    var selected = $('#ItemID').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: this.href,
        data: { id: selected }, // action parameter with selected value
        cache: false, // disable caching
        success: function (result) {
            // do something to target DOM
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

**Additional notes:**

1) Make sure that parameter(s) passed into `data` setting matches exactly with parameter(s) in the target controller action pointed by `href` attribute of the link.

```
public ActionResult TargetAction(int id)
{
    // do something 
}
```

2) You can use strongly-typed version of `DropDownList`, i.e. `DropDownListFor` to bind viewmodel property.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemID, ViewBag.Items as SelectList, ...)
```